# Textwrangler grep regex expression to remove every <span> except one

Tags: html, css, regex, macos, textwrangler

I am desperately looking to a Textwrangler grep syntax to remove all the multi language garbage from a cvs file.

I have a bunch of:

```
<span class="multilang" lang="en">Portugal</span><span class="multilang" lang="it">Portogallo</span><span class="multilang" lang="pt">Portugal</span><span class="multilang" lang="no">Portugal</span>
```

And I would like to remove the whole span tag and anything between

```
<span class="multilang" lang="en">
```

and the first occurrence of

```
</span>
```

and the text inside "Portugal" in this case. In this case it would remove

```
<span class="multilang" lang="en">Portugal</span>
```

Obviously "Portugal" is only an example, I have a lots of these kind of entries in the original csv.

I tried this:

```
</?span class="multilang" lang="en"*>(.*)(</span>).*\1
```

But it is not working at all. It cannot find anything.

Thank you in advance,
Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this:

```
<span class="multilang" lang="en">([^<]*)<\/span>
```

<kbd>[LiveDemo](https://www.regex101.com/r/eG0wC7/1)</kbd>

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked flawlessly but in the meanwhile I found the other suggest solution (see below).

Answer (score 0):

Ok thank you I found the answer on the Textwrangler manual:

```
</?span class="multilang" lang="en"*>(.*?)</span>
```

Page 146: http://pine.barebones.com/manual/TextWrangler_User_Manual.pdf